# Use data from one observable in another and then return result as other observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am solving this issue:

**The application flow:**

I have to call the first API endpoint (let's call it EP-A for simplicity) which takes Blob as body and fileType as a request parameter. Its performed via calling automatically generated class

```
  uploadFile$Response(params?: {
    fileType?: 'USER_AVATAR' | 'UNKNOWN' | 'DELIVERY_LOGO' | 'PAYMENT_LOGO' | 'ITEM_PICTURE';
    body?: { 'file'?: Blob }
  }): Observable<StrictHttpResponse<FileUploadResponse>> {

    const rb = new RequestBuilder(this.rootUrl, FileControllerService.UploadFilePath, 'post');
    if (params) {
      rb.query('fileType', params.fileType, {});
      rb.body(params.body, 'application/json');
    }

    return this.http.request(rb.build({
      responseType: 'blob',
      accept: '*/*'
    })).pipe(
      filter((r: any) => r instanceof HttpResponse),
      map((r: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        return r as StrictHttpResponse<FileUploadResponse>;
      })
    );
  }
```

The `StrictHttpResponse<T>` is simply an interface holding a "generic" body (so you can retrieve data that will have a structure defined by swagger from which this method is generated).

Then the result `FileUploadResponse` which is an object like

```
{
 uuid: string,
 time: Timestamp

 ...
 Other members omitted for simplicity
 ...
}
```

is sent to another EP (let's call it `EP-B`) **right after** `EP-A` call returns a value, `EP-B` takes an object below as a body and currently logged person as a path variable.

```
{
 uuid: string
}
```

So before calling EP-B the result from EP-A should be parsed (in this case, the uuid field should be taken and put into a new object for EP-B calling)

Again via the generated method with a similar signature as the one above (and I will omit it for simplicity).

If everything performed well, I´d like to let the caller know about that. If anything failed (any of these 2 EP calls), I´d like to let it know to call of this method to react somehow (show alert, change page somehow, ...)

The method I have is now incomplete, I do not know how to "connect" these 2 Observables, I´ve read about mergeMap, flatMap, etc. but I am not sure how to use it in my case.

```
  updateUserAvatar(avatar: Blob): Observable<boolean> {

    return new Observable<boolean>((observer) => {

      // Calling EP-A
      this.avatarFormChangeRequestSubscription = this.fileControllerService.uploadFile$Response({
        fileType: 'USER_AVATAR',
        body: {
          file: avatar
        }
      })
        .subscribe((response: StrictHttpResponse<FileUploadResponse>) => {
            // Handle returned UUID and somehow pass it into an observable belog
            console.log(response);
          },
          (error: any) => {
            observer.error(error);
          });

      // Creating object for EP-B calling
      const avatarUpdateParams = {
        id: 1, // Just dummy ID for now, will be dynamically changed
        body: {
          avatarUUID: '' // the UUID from observable response above should be placed here
        }
      };

      // Calling EP-B
      this.avatarFormChangeRequestSubscription = this.userControllerService.updateUserAvatar$Response(avatarUpdateParams)
        .subscribe((response: StrictHttpResponse<string>) => {
          // Handle successfull avatar upload (change the "Logged user" object avatar to change it everywhere etc
          console.log(response);
          observer.next(true);
        },
          (error: any) => {
            observer.error(error);
          });
    });
  }
```

At the end I would like to add **"use case" flow** too to understand what I am trying to achieve from user view:

User uploads his photo which is firstly uploaded into a file system (and linked with database record) on BE side, then this file is linked to his profile as his profile picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it using `rxjs`. Something like that might works :

```
this.fileControllerService.uploadFile$Response({
    fileType: 'USER_AVATAR',
    body: {
      file: avatar,
    },
  })
  .pipe(
    tap((responseOfFirstApiCall: StrictHttpResponse<FileUploadResponse>) => {
      // Do whatever you want here, but you might not need that since you get the response below as well (in the flatMap)
      // Handle returned UUID and somehow pass it into an observable belog
      console.log(response);
    }),
    flatMap(
      (responseOfFirstApiCall: StrictHttpResponse<FileUploadResponse>) => {
        // Creating object for EP-B calling
        const avatarUpdateParams = {
          id: 1, // Just dummy ID for now, will be dynamically changed
          body: {
            avatarUUID: '', // the UUID from observable response above should be placed here
          },
        };

        return this.userControllerService.updateUserAvatar$Response(avatarUpdateParams);
      }
    ),
    tap((responseOfTheSecondApiCall: StrictHttpResponse<string>) => {
      // Handle successfull avatar upload (change the "Logged user" object avatar to change it everywhere etc
      console.log(response);
      observer.next(true);
    }),
    catchError((err: any) => of(err))
  )
  .subscribe(); // Empty subscribe() call to trigger the http request. Not needed if you get the result somewhere else (eg if your method return an observable that you want to handle the result somewhere else)
```

`flatMap()` is the same as mergeMap. Change it as you wish, there's a lot of option like `map` or `switchMap` that you should learn about since they are useful.

Basically, the `pipe` allow you to chain functions, and if there is an error, then the `catchError` is triggered.

Tip: Note that what is in the `pipe` is executed BEFORE the result of your api call. So if you want to do something with your result before to get it, then think about `rxjs`:

service

```
getUser(id: string) {
  return this._http.get<any>(url).pipe(
    map(result => result.email), // Return only the email
  );
}
```

component:

```
  ngUnsubscribe = new Subject();

  ngOnInit() {
    this._userService.getUser(1)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)) // Don't forget to unsubscribe !
    .subscribe(email => console.log('email = ', email))
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.unsubscribe();
    // or
    // this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    // this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer, It works like a charm. I have a one question about this. Is it possible to store that UUID somewhere in this merge map chain and use it if this whole "pipeline passed"? (if even the second call, to update avatar, was successful) Usage would be like: update my localStorage variable user-avatar. After this action I would like to update this avatar on 2 places. In component I call this "chain" from (which should be easy) and update header component which holds avatar too and which is not connected to this method calling.

Comment: You're welcome :) let's say this code is in a service. If you just need to reuse the UUID in the function containing this code, then you can declare a variable and store the UUID inside, you'll be able to use it in every step of the "chain". Now, if you want to use it outside the service, or in other function, or wherever you want, then declare your variable in your service (Then you'll be able to call `this.myService.myVariable` in a component for example). Remember that a service is, by default, a singleton, therefore your data won't change during the lifecycle of your application.